# Running python script on PHP throws error "Can't find a default Python. "

Tags: php, python, wamp, web-development-server

I am trying to run a python code in my PHP page by using

```
<?php

$command = "py C:/wamp/www/py/python.py 2>&1";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);

?>
```

But this just prints "Can't find a default Python. " on my webpage

My python code is

```
hello = "hello"
world = "world"
print (hello + " " + world)
```

I am using WAMP to run the php code

Comment: Have you tried editing `$command` to include the full path to the python executable? If your web server is running as a different user, it may not have access to the same set of environmental variables that you have when you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your python installation path to windows environment variables.

1. Right click your Computer and select Properties
2. Click Advanced system properties
3. Click Environment variables
4. On user variables select "Path" and click edit
5. Append your python installation path on there with ';' separator

   ex: C:\windows;C:\Python\Python27

If you have python 2 and 3 on your system
You can select the version with
`py -2` or `py -3`

Comment: I have already added python in my environment variables . I have also checked it in cmd by usin 'python -3' command.

Comment: How about using the full path? `"C:/Python/Python27/python" C:/wamp/www/py/python.py 2>&1`